# Rails 4.0.3: after_save callback seems to be called too soon?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

Given the following two classes Customer and Order, I have a problem which I have narrowed down to the execution times of the callbacks I am using.

The reason for the use of callbacks is that I need to store the aggregated diff of each customer without having to iterate through all of his/her orders each time. So I realized that it might be a good approach to use callbacks to first update the diff on each individual order *before* each save, and second, update the aggregated diff on the customer model *after* each order is saved.

The symptoms I get are weird seemingly random errors where it tells me that the diff between two orders which both totals $238 is $15. When I limited the debugger to the affected customers I realized that it was simply skipping the orders.each loop below (but only in some cases) because there were no orders associated to the customer.

Since all Customers have at least one order and the order is actually created before the customer in this system, that can't be true.

Is there some way I can enforce that the after_save callback is indeed not called until ActiveRecord has finished both saving the Order object and updating the relation to the Customer model?

As you can see I also tried to use a timer to see if I could get to work by sleeping the thread for a short while before continuing, but that did not work.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  has_many :orders
  before_save :calculate_shipping

  def update_total_diff
    sum = 0

    orders.each do |o|
      if o.diff.present?
        sum += o.diff
      end
    end

    # HERE IS THE PROBLEM: When inspecting the orders collection in the debuggger it is empty.

    # Make sure shipping is updated
    calculate_shipping

    # Since we are calculating the diff shipping must be subtracted
    sum -= shipping

    self.total_diff = sum
    self.save
  end

  ...

  private

    def calculate_shipping

      ...returns either 15 or 0

    end

end
```

And the Order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  belongs_to :customer
  before_save :update_diff
  after_save :update_customer

private
  def update_diff

    #Updates a local value
    ......

  end

  def update_customer

      #Here we trigger a function on the customer model in order to tell it that it needs to re-calculate

      sleep(1/10) #Tried this to test - no luck

      if self.customer_id.present? && diff.present?
        self.customer.update_total_diff
    end
  end
end
```

Edit:

Have a look at this:

```
From: /vagrant/app/models/order.rb @ line 23 Order#update_customer:

    21: def update_customer
    22:   if self.customer_id.present?
 => 23:     binding.pry
    24:   end
    25:     if self.customer_id.present? && diff.present?
    26:     self.customer.update_total_diff
    27:   end
    28: end

...

[4] pry(#<Order>)> michael = self.customer
=> #<Customer id: 2, name: "Michael xxx", mail: "xxx@gmail.com", shipping_address_id: 2, created_at: "2014-07-17 11:00:12", updated_at: "2014-07-17 11:00:12", shipping: #<BigDecimal:7fada4e707d0,'0.0',9(36)>, total_diff: nil>
[5] pry(#<Order>)> michael.orders
=> []
[6] pry(#<Order>)> michael = Customer.find(2)
=> #<Customer id: 2, name: "Michael xxx", mail: "xxx@gmail.com", shipping_address_id: 2, created_at: "2014-07-17 11:00:12", updated_at: "2014-07-17 11:00:12", shipping: #<BigDecimal:7fada5008098,'0.0',9(36)>, total_diff: nil>
[7] pry(#<Order>)> michael.orders
=> [#<Order id: 2, pledge_id: 4808304, amount: #<BigDecimal:7fada50fc120,'0.89E2',9(36)>, customer_id: 2, perk_id: 9, created_at: "2013-11-23 00:00:00", updated_at: "2014-07-17 11:00:12", diff: #<BigDecimal:7fada5108240,'0.0',9(36)>>]
[8] pry(#<Order>)>
```

I tried stopping my debugger right before the Order tells Customer to re-calculate. I tried assigning the same customer twice to the variable "michael". If I assign the variable simply with:
    michael = self.customer
The object won't know about any of its associated orders. If I assign it thorugh activerecord like so:
    michael = Customer.find(2)
It will work. Why is that?

For now I managed to fix it by doing this, but I'd still like to know if anyone can explain the situation for me?

```
me = Customer.find(id)

me.orders.each do |o|
  if o.diff.present?
    sum += o.diff
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you end up getting any more information on this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember how it turned out, but I think I settled with the fix above.